# Query Builder and Group By on two columns in Symfony2 / Doctrine generate duplicates

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm creating a message bundle where messages are grouped per contacts. On my index page, I display different threads. When you clic on one thread, it show all the messages exchanged between you and your contact. I use a Query Builder to display the threads on my index page:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
    ->where('m.from = ?1 or m.to = ?1')
    ->groupBy('m.to, m.from')
    ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter(1, $user->getId())
    ->setMaxResults($pagination) // limit
    ->setFirstResult($pagination * $page) // offset
;
```

If I have 3 entries, for exemple:

```
+----+------+----+
| id | from | to |
+----+------+----+
| 1  | 1    | 2  |
+----+------+----+
| 2  | 2    | 1  |
+----+------+----+
| 3  | 1    | 2  |
+----+------+----+
```

I expect:

```
+----+------+----+
| id | from | to |
+----+------+----+
| 3  | 1    | 2  |
+----+------+----+
```

But I get:

```
+----+------+----+
| id | from | to |
+----+------+----+
| 2  | 2    | 1  |
+----+------+----+
| 3  | 1    | 2  |
+----+------+----+
```

I found a way to do it with SQL, using the same alias for from_id and to_id:

```
SELECT id, from_id as c, to_id as c FROM Message WHERE c = 1 GROUP BY from_id, to_id
```

But I don't know how to do it with Doctrine.

EDIT:

Until I get a better idea, I use a key to easily "group by".

```
// entity

/**
* @ORM\Column(name="key", type="string", length=40)
*/
private $key;

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 */
public function setOnPrePersist()
{
    if($this->from < $this->to) {
        $key = $this->from . 't' . $this->to;
    } else {
        $key = $this->to . 't' . $this->from;
    }

    $this->key = $key;
}

// query builder

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
    ->where('m.from = ?1 or m.to = ?1')
    ->groupBy('m.key')
    ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter(1, $user->getId())
    ->setMaxResults($pagination) // limit
    ->setFirstResult($pagination * $page) // offset
;

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: try selectiong only the id adding `$qb->select("m.to, m.from");`

Comment: I tried $q = $em->createQueryBuilder()->select('m.to, m.from')->from('MyAppDiscussionBundle:Message', 'm')... but I get an error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 9 near 'to, m.from FROM': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: You're expecting the wrong thing. In SQL, using `GROUP BY from_id, to_id` means that from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 1 are 2 different groups.

Comment: Is there a way to indicate data from "to_id" and "from_id" are the same and apply a group by on it ?

Answer (score 12):

in case that you have many columns in 'group by' you must use addGroupBy() method.

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m')
    ->where('m.from = ?1 or m.to = ?1')
    ->groupBy('m.to')
    ->addGroupBy('m.from')
    ->orderBy('m.date', 'DESC')
    ->setParameter(1, $user->getId())
    ->setMaxResults($pagination) // limit
    ->setFirstResult($pagination * $page) // offset
;
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following its by using doctrine DQL method -

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT m.id, m.from_id as c, m.to_id as c FROM AcmeDemoBunlde:Message as m WHERE m.c = 1 GROUP BY m.from_id, m.to_id"); 

$messageDetails = $query->getResult();
```

Instead of **AcmeDemoBundle** replace with your appropriate bundle name.

Comment: It doesn't work but I'm exploring a solution using DQL and IDENTITY() http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html