# Doctrine: is it safe to call QueryBuilder::groupBy() with multiple arguments?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Is it safe to call Doctrine's [Query Builder](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/query-builder.html) ::groupBy() with multiple arguments, e.g:

```
$qb->select('e')    
  ->from('Entity', 'e')
  ->groupBy('e.foo', 'e.bar');
```

Instead of:

```
$qb->select('e')    
  ->from('Entity', 'e')
  ->groupBy('e.foo')
  ->addGroupBy('e.bar');
```

From what I can see in the [codebase](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php#L1149) they call `func_get_args()`, so it should take multiple arguments. Both queries generate same SQL.

However, it doesn't seem to be documented. Moreover, from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35572615/1555546):

> in case that you have many columns in 'group by' you must use
>   addGroupBy()

So why? Is that an undocumented feature that may be removed one day or smth?